# Flash android app Null object refference

Tags: flash, button

Everytime I want to access the addSelectionMenu it says its a null object reference and it also happened with the 'vorige' button and I have been stuck  for a couple of days now. Could someone explain me what I did wrong?

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;



public class MakeNewAccountPage extends MovieClip {
    var myTextTitel:TextField;
    var myTextUsername:TextField;
    var myTextPassword:TextField;
    var myTextOverigeInfo:TextField;
    var backGround:Back_Ground;
    var vorige:Vorige;
    var instellingen:Instellingen;
    ///////Buttons in categorie menu//////
    var categorieBtn:CategorieBtn;
    var bankAccountBtn:BankAccountBtn;
    var gameAccountBtn:GameAccountBtn;
    var schoolAccountBtn:SchoolAccountBtn;
    var websiteAccountBtn:WebsiteAccountBtn;
    var werkAccountBtn:WerkAccountBtn;
    var wifiAccountBtn:WifiAccountBtn;
    var overigeBtn:OverigeBtn;


    public function MakeNewAccountPage() {
        myTextTitel = new TextField();
        myTextUsername = new TextField();
        myTextPassword = new TextField();
        myTextOverigeInfo = new TextField();
        ///////buttons in menu////
        categorieBtn = new CategorieBtn();
        bankAccountBtn = new BankAccountBtn();
        gameAccountBtn = new GameAccountBtn();
        schoolAccountBtn = new SchoolAccountBtn();
        websiteAccountBtn = new WebsiteAccountBtn();
        werkAccountBtn = new WerkAccountBtn();
        wifiAccountBtn = new WifiAccountBtn();
        overigeBtn = new OverigeBtn();



        vorige  = new Vorige();
        backGround = new Back_Ground();
        instellingen = new Instellingen();
        vorige.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Previous);
        categorieBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,CatogoryMenu);
    }
    public function LoadMakeNewPage(_stage:Stage):void{
        if(!_stage.contains(backGround)){
            _stage.addChild(backGround);
        }
        if(!_stage.contains(vorige)){
            vorige.x = 0;
            vorige.y = 18;
            _stage.addChild(vorige);
        }
        if(!_stage.contains(instellingen)){
            instellingen.x = 358,15;
            instellingen.y = 18;
            _stage.addChild(instellingen);
        }
        if(!_stage.contains(categorieBtn)){
            categorieBtn.x = 138,8;
            categorieBtn.y = 109,1;
            _stage.addChild(categorieBtn);
            }
        if(!_stage.contains(myTextTitel)){
            myTextTitel.x = 138,3;
            myTextTitel.y =188,25 ;
            myTextTitel.width = 200;
            myTextTitel.height = 35;
            myTextTitel.border = true;
            myTextTitel.borderColor = 0x000000;
            myTextTitel.type = "input";
            myTextTitel.background = true;
            myTextTitel.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            myTextTitel.multiline = true;
            myTextTitel.wordWrap = true;
            _stage.addChild(myTextTitel);
        }
        if(!_stage.contains(myTextUsername)){
            myTextUsername.x = 138,3;
            myTextUsername.y = 280;
            myTextUsername.width = 200;
            myTextUsername.height = 35;
            myTextUsername.border = true;
            myTextUsername.borderColor = 0x000000;
            myTextUsername.type = "input";
            myTextUsername.background = true;
            myTextUsername.backgroundColor =  0xFFFFFF;
            myTextUsername.wordWrap = true;
            myTextOverigeInfo.multiline = true;
            _stage.addChild(myTextUsername);
        }
        if(!_stage.contains(myTextPassword)){
            myTextPassword.x = 138,3;
            myTextPassword.y = 340;
            myTextPassword.width = 200;
            myTextPassword.height = 35;
            myTextPassword.border = true;
            myTextPassword.borderColor = 0x000000;
            myTextPassword.type = "input";
            myTextPassword.background = true;
            myTextPassword.backgroundColor =  0xFFFFFF;
            myTextPassword.wordWrap = true;
            myTextOverigeInfo.multiline = true;
            _stage.addChild(myTextPassword);
        }
        if(!_stage.contains(myTextOverigeInfo)){
            myTextOverigeInfo.x = 138,3;
            myTextOverigeInfo.y = 461,9;
            myTextOverigeInfo.width = 200;
            myTextOverigeInfo.height = 65;
            myTextOverigeInfo.border = true;
            myTextOverigeInfo.borderColor = 0x000000;
            myTextOverigeInfo.type = "input";
            myTextOverigeInfo.background = true;
            myTextOverigeInfo.backgroundColor =  0xFFFFFF;
            myTextOverigeInfo.multiline = true;
            myTextOverigeInfo.wordWrap = true;
            _stage.addChild(myTextOverigeInfo);
        }

    }
    public function CatogoryMenu(e:MouseEvent):void{
            addSelectionMenu(this.stage);
        }
        public function addSelectionMenu(_stage:Stage):void{
            trace(bankAccountBtn);
            if(!_stage.contains(bankAccountBtn)){
                bankAccountBtn.x = 138,3;
                bankAccountBtn.y = 144,1;
                _stage.addChild(bankAccountBtn);
            }
            if(!_stage.contains(gameAccountBtn)){
                gameAccountBtn.x = 138,3;
                gameAccountBtn.y = 179,1;
                _stage.addChild(gameAccountBtn);
            }
            if(!_stage.contains(schoolAccountBtn)){
                schoolAccountBtn.x = 138,3;
                schoolAccountBtn.y = 214,1;
                _stage.addChild(schoolAccountBtn);
            }
            if(!_stage.contains(websiteAccountBtn)){
                websiteAccountBtn.x = 138,3;
                websiteAccountBtn.y = 249,1;
                _stage.addChild(websiteAccountBtn);
            }
            if(!_stage.contains(werkAccountBtn)){
                werkAccountBtn.x = 138,1;
                werkAccountBtn.y = 284,1;
                _stage.addChild(werkAccountBtn);
            }
            if(!_stage.contains(wifiAccountBtn)){
                wifiAccountBtn.x = 138,1;
                wifiAccountBtn.y = 319,1;
                _stage.addChild(wifiAccountBtn);
            }
            if(!_stage.contains(overigeBtn)){
                overigeBtn.x = 138,1;
                overigeBtn.y =  354,1;
                _stage.addChild(overigeBtn);
            }


        }
    public function Previous(m:MouseEvent):void{
        if(vorige){
            //RemoveMenu7(this.stage);
            //Main(parent.parent).StartMenu();
        }
    }
    public function RemoveMenu7(_stage:Stage):void{
        if(_stage.contains(vorige)){
            _stage.removeChild(vorige);
        }
        if(_stage.contains(instellingen)){
            _stage.removeChild(instellingen);
        }
        if(_stage.contains(backGround)){
            _stage.removeChild(backGround);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: its the error 1009 cant access a property or method of a null object refference

Comment: if you trace the stage here: trace(bankAccountBtn); change it to trace(_stage); what's the result?

Comment: then it says that stage == Null